# Type Hinting a class with a method that returns a value dependant on __init__ argument

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Given a custom class with a function that returns a value dependant on a method passed to **init**, how can I tell mypy what the function returns? This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work for multiple reasons, like the fact that MyClass doesn't seem to be subscriptable in type hints.

```
_Var = TypeVar("_Var")

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, method: Callable[[Any], _Var]) -> None:
        ...

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs) -> _Var:
        ...


def a(method, *args, **kwargs) -> MyClass[int]:
    k = MyClass(method)
    ...
    return k

instance = a(...)
value = instance.run()  # int
```

Comment: looks like generics might be your thing. the `Generic` construct i mean.

Comment: Amazing, that solves everything. If you submit that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: they may well not submit an answer as this is almost certainly a duplicate